# Record types, with their corresponding reason and subreasons

Tags: case, picklist, record-type, service

I am new to Salesforce Service, I would like to generate a report or a SOQL query to retrieve all record types, with their corresponding reason and subreasons. All the queues with notification steps and users inside each queue.

Can I get into one report or into separate reports? Or into one query or separated queries?

All I know is the RecordType and Queue objects can be used: `SELECT Name FROM RecordType`

Comment: Could you explain what a subreason is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no simple way to do this via a SOQL query. Your best bet is the UI API, which you can query via [Salesforce Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php).

Go to Utilities, REST Explorer and do a `GET` request to this URL:

`/services/data/v58.0/ui-api/object-info/Case/picklist-values/012Ae000000L056IAC/Reason`

The Id in the URL is the Id of the record type. (You can get that yourself via SOQL: `SELECT Id, Name FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Case'`)